# symfony concurrent requests with webhook

Tags: php, symfony4, telegram-bot

I am developing a bot for telegram, using webhook. I experienced a problem that at the same time it is not possible to work with two or more users. Those. Until the function processing the request from the telegram server completes its execution, the request with a message from another user will not be processed.
P.S. I use ngrok so that my localhost is accessible at the address, and in the web interface, I see how several requests come from the telegram server (I wrote to the bot from three different accounts), but they are processed in turn.
 I tried the same thing on spring boot, everything works fine there. I am almost unfamiliar with the symphony; it wasn’t possible to google this topic. Is it possible to solve this problem? Thanks.

[image: ngrok web interface]

when the user writes to the bot, the telegram server calls mysite .com / tg, and passes UpdateMessage, I get chat _id from it, and send a simple phrase to the user using the API.

```
    /**
 * @Route("/tg", name="tg")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function tg(Request $request)
{
    $update = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $tgBot = new TgBot('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    $tgBot->setMessage($update);

    $mas = explode(" ","lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing");
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($mas); ++$i){
        $tgBot->sendMessage(
            $tgBot->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
            $mas[$i]
        );
    }
```

**"sendMessage()"**
just sends a request to API using guzzle

Comment: It's unclear, specifically what is causing your concurrency issue here since there is no code to look at or much detail to go on. There are any number of possible issues with concurrency. 1) The browser has restrictions on number of concurrent requests. 2) Servers often have restrictions on number of concurrent requests per client 3) AJAX has both asynchronous and synchronous mode. 4) Server-side applications may block concurrent requests due to any number of reasons that involve locking backend data 5) It's an unknown if there is any issue here at all since there's no solid proof of it

Comment: @Sherif, thank you for your attention, I added information to the question.